# Compile Error in Playframework 2.0

Tags: batch-file, playframework, playframework-2.0

Compiling a Playframework-2.01 project I got the following output:

```
[java-ebean-templ] $ compile
[info] Updating {file:/home/sb/workspace/java-ebean-templ/}java-ebean-templ...
[info] Done updating.                                                                  
[error] {file:/home/sb/workspace/java-ebean-templ/}java-ebean-templ/compile:sources: PlayException: Compilation error [Not parsed?]
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed May 30, 2012 9:41:00 AM
[java-ebean-templ] $
```

and nothing else! What does it mean?

Comment: have you tried the play mailing list?

Answer (score 1):

Agree that the error message is not very clear.

This message seems to appear in my case when there is a syntax error in the scala view templates. So make sure they are clean before searching any further.

Comment: Yup, that was it. I had a compilation error in my views which was causing other things to fail. Thanks!